# Python's 'with' statement versus 'with .. as'

Tags: python, syntax

Having just pulled my hair off because of a difference, I'd like to know what the difference *really* is in Python 2.5.

I had two blocks of code (`dbao.getConnection()` returns a MySQLdb connection).

```
conn = dbao.getConnection()
with conn:
    # Do stuff
```

And

```
with dbao.getConnection() as conn:
    # Do stuff
```

I thought these would have the same effect but apparently not as the `conn` object of the latter version was a `Cursor`. Where did the cursor come from and *is* there a way to combine the variable initialization and with statement somehow?

Comment: The second version does initialize a variable, conn.  What actual problem are you having?  What worked differently?  What error did you get?  Can you include some output to show the problem?

Comment: Sorry. Thought it would have been clear from the description. dbao.getConnection() returns a MySQLdb connection so conn = dbao.getConnection() results in a conn being a Connection object while "with dbao.getConnection() as conn" results in conn being a Cursor object. The error message was that in the latter case conn did not have a rollback method which it shouldn't have as it was a Cursor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general terms, the value assigned by the `as` part of a `with` statement is going to be whatever gets returned by the [`__enter__` method of the context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__enter__).

Comment: Was suspecting this. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 38):

It may be a little confusing at first glance, but

```
with babby() as b:
    ...
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
b = babby()
with b:
    ...
```

To see why, here's how the context manager would be implemented:

```
class babby(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return 'frigth'

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        pass
```

In the first case, the name `b` will be bound to whatever is returned from the `__enter__` method of the context manager. This is often the context manager itself (for example for file objects), but it doesn't have to be; in this case it's the string `'frigth'`, and in your case it's the database cursor.

In the second case, `b` is the context manager object itself.

Comment: At times like these I wish I could award two answers. :|

Comment: @Mikko: IMHO this is the better -- if for not other reason than it is more detailed and discusses the differences -- answer and should be the accepted one.

Comment: @martineau: Since we're commenting on old comments! Yes, this answer is more detailed and discusses the differences. It gives more background information and in that sense it is better. But as an answer it is upside down. The accepted answer manages to answer the specific question in the (first) two lines. With this one I need to read through example cases, etc. before receiving an answer to the question. A perfect answer would have the accepted answer as the first paragraph followed by this one. Background info is nice, but sometimes it's also refreshing to just get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The with statement is there to allow for example making sure that transaction is started and stopped correctly.

In case of database connections in python, I think the natural thing to do is to create a cursor at the beginning of the with statement and then commit or rollback the transaction at the end of it.

The two blocks you gave are same from the with statement point of view. You can add the as to the first one just as well and get the cursor.

You need to check how the with support is implemented in the object you use it with.

See http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement