# Pythonic way of closing/terminating an object

Tags: multithreading, python

I have a Whoosh (file indexer) writer object

```
>>> a
<whoosh.filedb.filewriting.SegmentWriter object at 0x013DFE10>
```

As whoosh doesnt allow mutiple writers and implement thread safety (AFAIK!!), I would like to **close** that object when it has been used.

```
>>> a.is_closed
False
```

But it has no close method. I was assured that all mature python library objects have internal functions such as __ exit__ that allow all basic functionality. What is the right way of closing a Python object? Or does it depend on the library itself? I take the "a single but obvious way to do it right" way of Python in it's literal form

Here's the paste of dir(a): http://pastebin.com/Q5hceTr8

---

**Postscript**

I just learned about the with statement just a day before by asking on [Confused about Python's with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898257/confused-about-pythons-with-statement) . This question is distinct because I needed a way to handle a global object; so that I can do a commit after multiple additions or deletions. Seems like whoosh has a searcher.close() but not an indexer.close(), which seems inconsistent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, that means it implements the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers), and you should use it like this:

```
with constructor(args) as a:
    # do stuff with a
    pass
# here a is closed even if you had an error above
```

Where `constructor` is either the class itself or whatever factory function you use to create it. In Python 2.5 you need to `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Answer (score 5):

> I was assured that all mature python library objects have internal functions such as __ exit__ that allow all basic functionality.

They do, and your pastebin indicates such - see `__exit__` at the top?

This is a special method used to implement the following...

> What is the right way of closing a Python object?

Automatically, using a with-block:

```
with some_api_call() as awesome_thing_from_api:
    use(awesome_thing_from_api)
```

Comment: haha someone one else who names and thinks about programming nomenclature like i