# When to use "with" in python

Tags: python

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903557/pythons-with-statement-versus-with-as), and I understand when you would want to use `with foo() as bar:`, but I don't understand when you would just want to do:

```
bar = foo()
with bar:
   ....
```

Doesn't that just remove the tear-down benefits of using `with ... as`, or am I misunderstanding what is happening?  Why would someone want to use just `with`?

Comment: You probably don't want to do `with foo:` in _this_ case. `foo` is a callable, and the result of that callable will almost certainly be the context manager you want to exit, not the callable itself. But `with bar:` is perfectly reasonable here, as in @freakish's answer.

Comment: You are right; I changed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand a bit on @freakish's answer, `with` guarantees entry into and then exit from a "context".  What the heck is a context?  Well, it's "whatever the thing you're with-ing makes it".  Some obvious ones are:

- locks: you take a lock, manipulate some data, and release the lock.
- external files/streams: you open a file, read or write it, and close it.
- database records: you find a record (which generally also locks it), use some fields and maybe
  change them, and release the record (which also unlocks it).

Less obvious ones might even include certain kinds of exception trapping: you might catch divide by zero, do some arithmetic, and then stop catching it.  Of course that's built into the Python syntax: `try` ... `except` as a block!  And, in fact, `with` is simply a special case of Python's try/except/finally mechanisms (technically, `try/finally` wrapped around another `try` block; see comments).

The `as` part of a `with` block is useful when the context-entry provides some value(s) that you want to use inside the block.  In the case of the file or database record, it's obvious that you need the newly-opened stream, or the just-obtained record.  In the case of catching an exception, or holding a lock on a data structure, there may be no need to obtain a value from the context-entry.

Comment: `with` isn't really a special case of `try`/`except`, either conceptually or in reality. It's closer to a special case of `try`/`finally`, but even that isn't really accurate. (It's actually a `try`/`except`/`else` inside a `try`/`finally`, with at least two explicit calls to `__exit__` in different places.)

Comment: @abarnert: true; I was trying to simplify, and maybe over-simplified. :-)

Comment: But I think it's a little misleading this way. It's the `finally` that's the key part to what a `with` block intuitively does, not the `except`. (BTW, I wish whoever downvoted this would have added a comment, because I don't think my comment is enough justification for a vote, and if there's a different problem it's worth actually raising it so the answer can be improved, instead of drive-by voting displeasure.)

Comment: Ah, I think part of the issue here is that I "think of" the complete construct (`try ... except ... else ... finally`) as a "try/except" block.  That is, for me, the label using two of the four keywords identifies the entire construct.  But it is ambiguous and obviously others will interpret it differently (which is why I added the "technically" part after your earlier comment).

Comment: But you can't actually implement it as a single `try…except…else…finally` construct. And the inner `try…except` is basically just an implementation detail to make uncommon cases work better. The outer `try…finally` is the whole point. See http://pastebin.com/LQV9HPWZ for an explanation with formatted code.

Comment: "The outer try…finally is the whole point": exactly.  That's a block that, in python, *can* contain up to four keywords.  In other languages that have exceptions, similar rules apply but with different keywords.  If I were talking about Lisp I would have used the phrase "unwind-protect", when I talk about Python I tend to use "try/except" to cover the same concept.  So I meant the same as if I had written "`with` is a special case of Python's unwind-protect."  After that, *everything* is mere implementation detail. :-)

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. `try…except` without a `finally` doesn't do the equivalent of `with`, and isn't the equivalent of `unwind_protect`. But if you're just using it `try…except` as shorthand for [the `try` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) in general, rather than specifically for `try1_stmt` without a `finally` suite, that's reasonable—especially since you've long since edited the answer to clear up any possible confusion.

Answer (score 5):

For example when you want to use `Lock()`:

```
from threading import Lock
myLock = Lock()
with myLock:
   ...
```

You don't really need the `Lock()` object. You just need to know that it is on.

Comment: I think you mean "You don't really need the Lock object."

Comment: @martineau: It may be a bit confusing, but I don't think it's wrong or misleading. What could "the `Lock()` object" mean but "the object returned by the `Lock()` call"?

Comment: @abarnert: Exactly, you _do_ need the returned object for the `with`, not the `Lock` object (class) itself. Which is way I think what was said is wrong.

Comment: @martineau: In Python, `Lock()` doesn't refer to the `Lock` class, it refers to an instance of the `Lock` class. Why would you expect the opposite to be true in English? I agree that it could be clearer—e.g., just say "the `myLock` object"—but I don't think it's wrong as-is.

Comment: @abarnert: OK, `Lock()` isn't actually a class, it's a factory function that returns a `thread.lock` object which is very similar usage-wise. That's why I objected to the statement in the answer saying you really didn't need it -- meaning the value it returns -- since you really _do_, for example, for use in a `with` statement or to manually call its `acquire()` and `release()` methods.

Comment: @martineau: Now I get it. He's saying that you don't need the object _inside the `with` block_. You're saying that you do need the object _in the `with` clause_. You're both right, just about different things.

Comment: @abarnert: Perhaps that's what he meant...a clarification comment from the author at this point would sure be nice.

Comment: @martineau Perhaps? Obviously that's what I meant. What else could it mean? Stop niggling.

Comment: Obviously it wasn't obvious...and you could have stopped the quibbling yourself a long time ago.

Answer (score 4):

Using `with` without `as` still gets you the exact same teardown; it just doesn't get you a new local object representing the context.

The reason you want this is that sometimes the context itself isn't directly useful—in other words, you're only using it for the side effects of its context enter and exit.

For example, with a `Lock` object, you have to already have the object for the `with` block to be useful—so, even if you need it within the block, there's no reason to rebind it to another name. The same is true when you use `contextlib.closing` on an object that isn't a context manager—you already have the object itself, so who cares what `closing` yields?

With something like `sh.sudo`, there isn't even an object that you'd have any use for, period.

There are also cases where the point of the context manager is just there to stash and auto-restore some state. For example, you might want to write a `termios.tcsetattr`-stasher, so you can call `tty.setraw()` inside the block. You don't care what the stash object looks like, all you care about is that it gets auto-restored.

`decimal.localcontext` can work in any of these ways—you can pass it an object you already have (and therefore don't need a new name for), or pass it an unnamed temporary object, or have it just stash the current context to be auto-restored. But in any of those cases.

There are some hybrid cases where sometimes you want the context, sometimes you don't. For example, if you just want a database transaction to auto-commit, you might write `with autocommit(db.begin()):`, because you aren't going to access it inside the block. But if you want it to auto-rollback unless you explicitly commit it, you'd probably write `with autorollback(db.begin()) as trans:`, so you can `trans.commit()` inside the block. (Of course often, you'd actually want a transaction that commits on normal exit and rolls back on exception, as in [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)'s `transaction` example. But I couldn't think of a better hybrid example here…)

[PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and its predecessors (PEP 310, PEP 340, and other things linked from 343) explains all of this to some extent, but it's understandable that you wouldn't pick that up on a casual read—there's so much information that isn't relevant, and it mainly just explains the mile-high overview and then the implementation-level details, skipping over everything in between.